# (boost C++ library) bootstrap.bat: ''Web' is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Tags: c++, boost, build

I am currently trying to build boost for visual studio 2019 (64 bit), however, when I run bootstrap.bat from both the visual studio terminal and the windows command prompt, I get the error as mentioned in the title.

Here are some screenshots:
[visual studio terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzHiP.png)
[windows command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQCpI.png)

Please note this is my first post on stack overflow so sorry if I haven't done something correctly. Thank you for reading this and taking the effort to help.

Comment: Don't have spaces or & character in the pathname.

Comment: Look at the top of your terminal. The compiler seems to think "Web" is separate. This is probably due to spacing. Bootstrap fails to run so the environment is not being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason boost does not like your current path. Either because of the & symbol or spaces. Try moving it to a more canonical path `C:\boost_1_75_0`

Comment: Ahh! Brilliant thank you, that solved it. So that's where the 'Web' came from.